# Updating variables in controller from view form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my view here:

```
<%= form_tag("/update", method: "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:ucity) %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:state) %>
    <%= submit_tag("submits") %>
<% end %>
```

which should get passed to my controller and access those variables using params[:ucity] and params[:ustate]

```
def update_params
    uparams = { :state => params[:ustate], :city => params[:ucity] }
end

def update
    update_params
    @scraper = Scraper.new(update_params)
end
```

but I cannot figure out how to get them into my model when I have

```
def fetch_10DayForecast(city, state)
    HTTParty.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/ddaf27afe5015709/forecast10day/q/" + state.to_s + "/" + city.to_s + ".xml")
end

def initialize(dparams)
    forecast_hash = fetch_10DayForecast(dparams[:city], dparams[:state])
    forecast(forecast_hash)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured my own question out if anyone comes across this. I was not clear on what the submit button was doing but I should not have been **getting** the "/update" path and should have been **posting** to the "/update" path. I took out the method: "get" from the view. I then added a post request in my routes.rb folder to the update path. Then I was free to use those variables that were stored in the params[:city] and params[:state] and could display them however I wanted.